# Please help me to write the function drawing code

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks, asymptote

Please help me to write the function drawing code

- polynomial function f(x) = x^3 – 5*x.
- polynomial function f(x,y) = x^3 – 5*y^2.

Comment: If you want to plot those functions the following link could be helpful https://latexdraw.com/plot-a-function-and-data-in-latex/

Comment: Unfortunately with tikz and pgfplots you can "only" plot explicit equations, so you need to reformulate the second one. After doing so you should be able to plot it yourself with the given [comment of Luis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600377/please-help-me-to-write-the-function-drawing-code#comment1505797_600377) and the [answer of Roland](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600382/95441).

Answer (score 1):

pgfplot code for the first function to start:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-6,xmax=6,domain=-5:5]          
            \addplot[red] {x^2 - 5*x };        
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]