# How do I draw a polynomial function?

Tags: plot, code, draw

- polynomial function f(x,y) = x^3 – 5*y^2.
- polynomial function f(x,y) = x^3 – 5*y^2.

Heading

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers because it's not showing much effort on your part. Please look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question. This may require you to show an attempt at a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` button.  If you could also expand your question beyond just "Heading", that would be helpful.

Comment: Besides from you already asked that [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600377/please-help-me-to-write-the-function-drawing-code).

Comment: actually the title of this questions is better than the other one. But the other one now has the answer. Can someone combine the two questions?